# Словообразование: удар, ударник, удариться

Tags: словообразование

Помогите, пожалуйста, выполнить задания!

Даны три слова: **УДАР**, **УДАРНИК** *(музыкант)*, **УДАРИТЬСЯ**.

**Необходимо:**

- Установить характер отношений между данными словами (находятся ли они в отношениях непосредственной или опосредованной производности).

**Далее** разбор каждого слова проводится по схеме:

- Установить непосредственно мотивирующие (мотивирующие) для каждого слова.
- Способ словообразования и словообразовательный формант.
- Морфонологические явления (если есть).
- Словообразовательное значение.
- Словообразовательная модель (с аргументирующими примерами)
- Словообразовательный тип (с аргументирующими примерами)
- Установить ступень производности

**Далее:**

- Восстановить словообразовательную цепочку, в которую входит данное слово (слова). Если это возможно, цепочку продолжить.
- Указать словообразовательную парадигму, в которую входит данное слово.

Comment: Как минимум опубликуйте свою попытку сделать задание!!!

Comment: Я подмахнула правку, а там у "пожалуйста" запятые сняты. А были! 8-(

Answer (score 3):

Этот сайт нужно использовать, как возможность получить ответ на сложные вопросы, а не как способ скинуть свою домашнюю работу на других людей и потом обмануть преподавателя. Удачи :)